# javascript higher order function variable undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, higher-order-functions

I have this array of objects and want the unique elements given a specific key.
The array looks like this:

```
var items = [
    {name: "item1", year : 2013, value : 100},
    {name: "item1", year : 2012, value : 97},
    {name: "item3", year : 2013, value : 93 },
    {name: "item3", year : 2012, value : 91 },
    {name: "item2", year : 2012, value : -6 },
    {name: "item2", year : 2011, value : -5 },
    {name: "item4", year : 2012, value : -36 },
    {name: "item3", year : 2011, value : 93 },
    {name: "item4", year : 2013, value : -35 },
    {name: "item1", year : 2011, value : 98},
    {name: "item2", year : 2013, value : -7 },
    {name: "item4", year : 2011, value : -37 },
    {name: "item5", year : 2013, value : 58 },
    {name: "item5", year : 2012, value : 55 },
    {name: "item5", year : 2011, value : 54 }];
```

I get the list of unique elements for the key name with the following function:

```
var unique = function (arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        if (prev.indexOf(curr.name) === -1) {prev.push(curr.name)}
        return prev;
    }, [])}
```

so when I do console.log(unique(items)) I get the correct array:

```
[ 'item1', 'item3', 'item2', 'item4', 'item5' ]
```

If I change `name` with `year` in curr.name i get the correct result.
I want to do a higher order function so I can both pass the array I am working on and the key, so I would do `unique(items, 'name')` or alternatively `unique(items, 'year')` however when I transform my unique function to this:

```
var unique = function (arr, criteria) {
    return arr.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        if (prev.indexOf(curr.criteria) === -1) {prev.push(curr.criteria)}
        return prev;
    }, [])}
```

and I do `console.log(unique(items, 'name'))` I get `undefined`!?
and if I do `console.log(unique(items, name)` I get an error ReferenceError: name is not defined !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access the property :

```
if (prev.indexOf(curr[criteria]) === -1) {prev.push(curr[criteria])}
```